# Am I required to clear the use of class, race, or sub-race found in sources outside of the PHB with my DM?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, races, class, player-communication

Am I required to clear the use of class, race, or sub-race found in sources outside of the PHB with my DM?

Comment: This is your second similar question, is this genuine curiosity, or is there a reason you don't want to just tell your DM about your character? Knowing the full picture may allow you to get a more useful answer.

Comment: I am new to the world of DnD and don’t want to annoy my DM with a thousand questions over text. I felt that this forum was an open space to ask questions and get answers but perhaps that’s not the case?

Comment: @Undead-bedhead this is not a forum, but it is open to your questions as long as they fit the guidelines. Some of our users may come off as discouraging due to trying to clarify and identify your problems, so that we can solve them. Don't worry, they are usually trying to help you.

Comment: As @Akixkisu says, mostly we are trying to help. In your case being new to D&D I think you might be better served with a single question along the lines of 'what should I discuss with my DM prior to my first game?', and answers will cover races, classes, stats, backstory etc. Speaking as a DM; having a player keen to communicate, learn and discuss is BRILLIANT, not annoying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is yes, although required might be too strong a word.

From my experience anything outside of the *Player's Handbook* should be cleared by your DM.  Now the DM may also give you a list of pre-approved books that you may choose character options from, but this should be discussed also.

Further, from my personal experience, it is a good idea to even discuss the class, race, and subclasses from the PHB with the DM.  When I DM, I appreciate being asked questions and discussing what my players are choosing, and I also enjoy giving them advice when they wish it.

Answer (score 5):

For most D&D groups it's praxis to clear any characters you make with the DM.

You're going to play the game together so it's good to get on the same page about things. D&D 5e can be played and ran in so many different ways—it's kind of the "all things to all people" edition—so it's good to talk to each other about the game world, the way the game is set up, the characters you intend to play and so on, especially if you're just starting out together.